# Read a “.mpp” file with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-project

I am working with windows form and through a dialog window with event "OpenFileDialog.OpenFile" but I have a problem since I try to read a Microsoft Project file with extension ".mpp"

Once the file is selected, it is my intention that the data within the ".mpp" file can be added to a DataSet or, failing that, stored in a SQL Server database

In if the question is: Can the data from an .mpp file be passed to a DataSet or database of SQL Server data?

Either option leaves me

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

there is open source lib (GNU License) , that will help you to read mpp file in C#

Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/net.sf.mpxj-for-csharp/

Source code :https://github.com/joniles/mpxj

Answer (score 0):

.MPP is a complex file format and you need a specific software to parse such files.

There are only two libraries that can reasonably parse MPP files:

- One is open-source MPXJ under GNU License.
- Another is proprietary [Aspose.Tasks](https://products.aspose.com/tasks). You can check how it works using free [Aspose.Tasks web-app](https://products.aspose.app/tasks/viewer) which is completely based on Aspose.Tasks.dll